# SXA Optimized Items Not Created Completely. Core Database error

Tags: sxa, performance-optimization, sxa-storefront

In 9.3 we are seeing the base themes not always generating the optimized items. The weird thing it will create the item, but never have the code attached.

We see the following in the logs. Why is the core database even required? The basic install does not include it. I think it might be something else as we didn't have the core database definition before and sometimes the process works.

```
Could create optimized item in/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/Commerce Main Theme/Scripts: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='core']
```

Comment: Do you have any specific patches in place for CD that impacts the core db?

Comment: Noticed Sitecore.Sites.Config might be causing the issue. By default it is not disabled for CD.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the sites defined in Sitecore.Sites.Config referenced core. Removing them from Content Delivery with a patch fixed the issue and optimization was working again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentDelivery">
    <sites>
      <site name="shell">
        <patch:delete />
      </site>
      <site name="login">
        <patch:delete />
      </site>
      <site name="modules_shell">
        <patch:delete />
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```